# Nodejs Multipart File Upload, Resulting File Larger Than Original

Tags: node.js, express, encoding, upload, multipart

I wanted to write a file uploader for a Nodejs Server using Express 4. I didn't want to use any middleware to achieve this because this was more of an academic exercise to understand a better how Nodejs works and multipart uploads.

Below is just the main bit of code for a route in Express 4 that collects the client data and writes it out.

```
var clientData = [];
// When Data Arrives
req.on('data', function(data){
    clientData.push(data);
});
// Done
req.on('end', function(){
    var output  = Buffer.concat(clientData);
    fs.writeFile('Thisisthesong.mp3', output, 'binary', function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        debug('Wrote out song');
    });
});
```

My issue is that when the file is finally written out, is larger than the original. For example, if I were to upload an MP3 with this code that was originally 10.5 MB the result is 11 MB. I believe it has something to do with switching the encodings back and forth from the body to writing it out. I also understand that node does not truly have a binary encoding, could that be an issue?

I also thought it could be because I'm not stripping the boundaries or the the Content-Disposition for the data (this would be the next step once this is working well), but the boundary and the Disposition are only about 300 bytes not 500KB. Does anybody have an explanation or could point out what I'm doing incorrectly, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
Other Info:
+ Express 4
+ I'm not using any middleware at the moment besides cookieparser
+ Ubuntu 12.04
+ Node v0.10.31
```

Comment: I have to ask if you're comparing the sizes using the same interface. For example, I have a downloaded zip which shows 2.3MB in Finder, but 2.2MB in Terminal using `ls -lah`.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple Hi Timothy. That's very interesting. I thought I was using the same interface to check the sizes, the file explorer and it reported different sizes. I think the file select from the browser is counting Kbytes different. When I checked them with ls -lah it did report them with same size. To look into this further I checked the two file with `wc -c` to get a strict byte count. The difference was only a couple hundred bytes which would account for the boundary and disposition. Thanks learned an important lesson today haha. Do you think I should delete this?

Comment: No, might be a good resource for others who have similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that you're comparing apples to apples here. Different interfaces on the operating system can calculate the size in different ways which could show a difference of hundreds of kilobytes for the exact same file. For example, I have a file on my computer right now which shows 2.3MB in Finder, but shows 2.2MB in Terminal when using ls -h.

Comment: So why is Ubuntu counting a KB as 1000 bytes and not 1024 Bytes. Is this more for the average user that would assume Kilo (as in simply 1000) or is KB as 1024 on the way out?

Comment: I don't know all of the discussion that went into it, but Ubuntu has stated that they are changing their units policy. Take a look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy